# Starting application from Home screen Icon coming to main Activity instead of reataing the current state

Tags: android

In my application i am starting another activity without finishing the first one becuase i am handling on activity result of the started activity.

Now the problem which I am facing in this case is while clicking on the icon present on home screen taking me again on the main Activity and the started activity is also present on background.

And if I am launching the application by long pressing the home button i am coming to the current state of application but it should come in case of home screen icon click also.

I am not getting what the issue is ??

Comment: actually i am little bit surprised because this is happening in Galaxy S2 with version 2.3.6 only in rest of the devices like S1 and another s2 also its working fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this is a device issue not the application one because it is working fine with other devices with the same model as well as OS . The device is having 2.3.6 in it and I have also tested it in other devices and in that case also worked as expected so i think it the device problem only.